# Как найти слово в строке, и вывести текст?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Добрый День, у меня вопрос:

**Есть строка например:**

`abracadabra-cudsa_123-qwerty-text_a-abraca-trollololo-nlo`

Если в строке есть слово(маркер) = `text_a` то вывести: `Привет Васа!`

Если в строке есть слово(маркер) = `text_b` то вывести: `Привет Лана!`

Если в строке не найдено `text_a` или `text_b` то вывести дефолт: `Привет Мир!`

**Я делаю так:**

```
$text = $_GET['text'];

$main_str = $text;

//искомый текст
$my_str = 'text_a';

$pos = strpos($main_str, $my_str);
if ($pos === false) {
  echo 'Привет Мир!';
}else{
  echo 'Привет Васа!';
}
```

Но тут проблема что ищет только одно слово (маркер)
Помогите решить! Спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
$text = $_GET['text'];

$main_str = $text;

if (strpos($main_str, 'text_a') !== false) {
  echo 'Привет Васа!';
} elseif (strpos($main_str, 'text_b') !== false) {
  echo 'Привет Лана!';
} else {
  echo 'Привет Мир!';
}
```

P.S. А что нужно делать, если найдены оба?

Answer (score 2):

```
$text = $_GET['text'];

$main_str = $text;

$has_a = strpos($main_str, 'text_a') !== false;
$has_b = strpos($main_str, 'text_b') !== false;

if ($has_a && $has_b) {
    echo 'ОШИБКА';
} else {
    if ($has_a) {
        echo 'А';
    } elseif ($has_b) {
        echo 'Б';
    } else {
        echo 'ПУСТО';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

раз уж стоит метка `регулярные-выражения`

```
<?php

$main_str = 'abracadabra-cudsa_123-qwerty-text_a-abraca-trollololo-nlo';

//искомый текст
$my_str = '/text_a|text_b/';

$matches = array();
preg_match_all($my_str, $main_str, $matches);

if (array_search('text_a', $matches[0]) !== false)
  echo 'Привет, Васа!';
elseif(array_search('text_b', $matches[0]) !== false)
  echo 'Привет, Лана!';
else
  echo 'Привет, Мир!';
```

Comment: поставил метку регулярные-выражения потому-что думал что через регулярные-выражения будет легче такое сделать, но тут почитал форумы, говорят что использование регулярных-выражений замедляет работу PHP.

Comment: все относительно, иногда быстрее написать регулярку с определенным синтаксисом и поведением, чем искать в ручную средствами php. Регулярка почти всегда лучше

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев: Не соглашусь с вами. Регулярка почти всегда лучше там, где она нужна - это да. Там где нет необходимости, лучше простыми строковыми функциями обойтись. Сложнее от этого не получится. Вы забываете что PHP написан на C. А в C строка - это на самом деле очень сложная структура из последовательностей `char`. Хотя с высоты `php` нам кажется что мы работаем со строками так-же как и, например, с цифрами.

Comment: я немного не об этом, понятно что из строки в 5 символов, узнать есть ли там символ гораздо проще с помощью спец метода в php, чем в регулярке, но для более сложного разбора (не просто поиска строки в подстроке) регулярка не обходима, и она на самом деле не такая уж и медленная, иначе был бы придуман альтернативный способ обработки)

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев: Видимо и вас не так понял и вы меня. Я не призываю не использовать регулярки вообще, Я призываю не использовать регулярки там, где можно работать с обычными строковыми функциями. За сим думаю далее не дискутировать, раз говорим о разных вещах)

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев вольюсь в вашу дискусию. Действительно алгоритм регулярок в php не однозначен т.е. чем больше строка и сложнее патерн тем выше степень выполненых операций. грубо говоря strpos просто просто пройдёться по строке и определит позицию линейно. т.е. `a` - количество данный будет пропорционально операциям как `10*a` а вот регулярка будет перебирать по символьно последовательно строку, и начинать перебор чуть ли не с начала строки `a^2` так что лучше использовать первый вариант т.к. при нем придел 'количества' данных выше чем в втором случае.

Comment: @Naumov я соглашусь, я в принципе и написал об этом. Простые операции не нужно совершать с помощью регулярки, она больше нужна для построение строки нужного формата, или приведение в неё (в строку нужного формата)

Comment: @Naumov: То, что вы пытаетесь сказать - называется алгоритм маляра Шлемиэля - забавная штука. Это именно то, что регулярка делает с исходной строкой. [Почитать](http://traditio.wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%B0_%D0%A8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%8D%D0%BB%D1%8F)

Comment: @ОлегДёгтев Ох, а я и незнал надо теорию подтягивать. Спс.